# Возможно ли передавать данные с веб-страницы(использую JavaScript) Windows приложению?

Tags: javascript

Пример: Есть web-страница, при её открытии в браузере нужно передать windows приложению информацию, допустим исходный код страницы, и всё это(передачу данных) нужно сделать с помощью JavaScript. Возможно ли это? Если да, то как?

Comment: windows приложению на том же компьютере, что и браузер? что именно за windows приложение? Никто не запрещает встроить в него микро сервер, тогда отправка данных из браузера будет выглядеть как обычный пост или гет запрос

Comment: Можно использовать кастомные протоколы (не знаю, как правильно называются). Этим пользуются, например, торрент-клиенты или тот же Телеграм.